# How to bundle less with WebPack without duplicates

Tags: css, webpack, less

I have the structure:
Page1.less
@import "colors.less";

Page2.less
@import "colors.less"

webpack config:

```
{
    test: /\.less$/i,
    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
         loader: "css-loader",
         options: { url: false },
     }, {
         loader: "less-loader",
         options: {
            lessOptions: { strictMath: true },
         },
    }],
},
```

As a result I have 2 files: 1.css -> related to page1 bundle, 2.css -> page2.
And there is "color.less" injected right to both of those files.

How could I setup the 3rd bundle: colors.css, and maybe not only colors. Let's call it "core.css", where I will have some styles.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong way to solving some kind of tasks.
The right way is:
Have file with only variables and functions:
theme.less

Have file with core styles: core.less (button.less, input.less and etc).
That file could @import theme.less

No one component should import core.less, only theme.less.

Then we should admin it with JS files and webpack basic bundle approach:
Button.js should import "button.less"
When we use "Button" somewhere it adds to dependencies also and button.less.
It avoids us to have duplicate styles in different compiled files.